# Initializr Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, updates, initializr

I had check that in the last version of [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) the Bootstrap integration (3.3.1) is not at the last update 3.3.5.
Can I update Bootstrap into initializr or I could have problems with the Initializr structure?

Do you have advices?
Thanks!!

Comment: Why not try it in a sandbox and find out for yourself?

Comment: Excuse me @JaredEitnier but I don't know what you mean..
I'm just a Web Designer, not a Developer :)